# Disowned jobs still stop on exit

Tags: bash

I connect to a remote server, and run something like this:

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/null & disown %-
```

Then I do `logout`, and reconnect, and `ps` shows no `cat` process running. Why?

Comment: Right before logging out, what does `jobs` say?

Comment: is this on a linux distribution using systemd?  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394

Comment: @Xen2050 nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command works on my end. It seems to take a lot of resources. Maybe you want to try:

```
sleep 999 & disown %-
```

and do a `ps aux | grep sleep` after a relogin instead.

However, if you know that you want to disown the process before you start it, you could just use nohup:

```
nohup sleep 999
```

Comment: It is possible that in your case user is still logged in somewhere. In mine, when I log off, nobody else is logged in.

Comment: No, the process is detached from the shell and keeps it's `pid` during logout/login - have you tried it with `sleep` ?

Comment: Apparently, it just didn't show when I did `ps` for some reason. It actually runs just fine. Any idea why doesn't it show for `ps` from the same user that started it?

Comment: No, `ps ux` should show it same user/same pid, except `sleep` finished and terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%%` or `%+` for the "current" (most recently backgrounded) job. `%-` is for the *previous* job, which is the second-most-recently stopped or backgrounded job. They mean the same thing if there's only one job. But if you'd left some background jobs running in an earlier part of your shell session or script, the way you're using `%-` probably isn't targeting the job you think it is.